# Inconvertible type, Cannot cast "com.example.apex.myapplication.shape" to "com.example.apex.myapplication.circle"

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I am creating a paint application and I used a `Drawingcanvas` class. Along with this class, I also used Shape classes`(circle, oval, rectangle and input text etc)`. My Problem is when I used if statement in my `DrawingCanvas` Class with all shapes I got one error every time (Inconvertible type, Cannot cast `"com.example.apex.myapplication.shape"`) to circle.oval, InputText etc.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mCurrentOperation == Constants.OPERATION_DRAW_PENCIL || mCurrentOperation == Constants.OPERATION_ERASE) {
                    mBrushPath.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                } else if (mCurrentOperation == Constants.OPERATION_MOVE_VIEW)

                {
                    if (mCanvasLeftBounds < xPos && xPos < mCanvasRightBounds && mCanvasTopBounds < yPos && yPos < mCanvasBottomBounds)

                    {

                        if (mShapeToMove instanceof Circle)
                        {
                            ((Circle) mShapeToMove)
                            ((Circle) mShapeToMove).setCenterX(xPos);
                            ((Circle) mShapeToMove).setCenterY(yPos);
```

Comment: What is Shape? which class it extends?

Comment: Can you post your com.example.apex.myapplication.shape class and your com.example.apex.myapplication.circle class, it wil be easier to answer that way

Comment: okay i am posting my code

Comment: package com.example.apex.myapplication;

public class Shape {

    public Shape() {
    }
}

Comment: Shape is a  Super class for all the Shape Modal class

Comment: @AkashDubey  Canvas Class which forms the canvas view.All the shapes are drawn on this view

Comment: So Shape would be a super class of all right?, then how it could be cast to Circle class!!

Comment: Actually buddy i am new to android application when i stuck in a problem that i could not understand then i come here to get help. I am creating a paint application